# Play output as in video

Tags: python, matplotlib, optimization, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to reproduce the code, but this ending doesn't happen. Could you help me? Link Youtube: [Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIK5Ikdoon8&ab_channel=sergiocorrea)

[Code video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ockT.png)

```
from colour import Color
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
plt.scatter(X, Y, color='blue')

#DC
plt.scatter(X[0], Y[0],color='red', marker='D')
plt.annotate("DC",(X[0]-1,Y[0]-5.5))

#imprimir as rotas
for r in range(len(rotas)):
for n in range(len(rotas[r])-1):
    i = rotas[r][n]
    j = rotas[r][n+1]
    plt.plot([X[i],X[j]], [Y[i],Y[j]], color=Color(r), alpha=0.4)
    
for r in range(len(temp_acum)):
    for n in range(len(temp_acum[r])):
        i = rotas[r][n]
        plt.annotate('$q_{%d}=%d$ |$t_{%d}=%d$'  %(i, q[i], i, temp_acum[r][n]), (X[i]+1,Y[i]))
    
patch = [mpatches.Patch(color=Color(n), label="Veiculo "+str(truck[n])+"|cap="+str(Q[truck[n]])) for n in range(len(truck))]
plt.legend(handles=patch,loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Distância X')
plt.ylabel('Distância Y')
plt.title('CVRPTW | Problema de Roteamento de Veículos com Janela de Tempos')
     
plt.show()
```

The graph ends up being generated, but with error warnings and does not have the route that each option can take.

My plot:

[image: My plot]

[image: Plot video]

Comment: Could you include the graph that you say you're generating, please?

Comment: Oh, yeah! Add in post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this will fix your entire problem but the second import line looks to have a syntax error. Rewrite it as:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Patches as mpatches
```

Also make an import for your plt variable:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: New error, in link: https://imgur.com/a/ytZgJcP

Comment: Sorry I’m not entirely familiar with what you are doing. I made an edit to the first import statement that I think should run correctly now.

Comment: New error, Mr. Larson. Link: https://imgur.com/a/m45wZ6A